# How to create more number of Jenkins jobs with single lib(Jar files) directory?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using selenium 2.47.1 and Jenkins 1.627 for automation process. I have already created one job in Jenkins & it is successfully running.In that, all files such as src, bin & lib(Jar files) directories are added into Work Place. Is there is any possible way to create Jenkins job by keeping lib(Jar files) separated to the workplace. So that different number of Jenkins job can use lib files. Because If we have lib file in each workplace means it takes lot of disk space. Is there is any way to achieve this..? Any help on this..

Comment: 1) Can you roughly state the file sizes in question here? 2) What OS is used to run Jenkins?

Comment: 1)Lib files are nearly taken 38 MB. If I creating another job in Jenkins, I have to add lib files once again to the workplace. Then it automatically consumes another 38 MB. 2) Jenkins is installed on Linux server

Comment: Wouldn't creating somewhere a directory and copying/moving files from workspace work for this?

Comment: It's unfortunate that the [Copy Artifacts](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) plugin really only does that - copying. I'd try to create a symbolic link directly to the directory holding the libs. You could have an extra job to update the libs. All downstream jobs automatically would see the new libs should they be updated. And well - 38MB is not _that_ much. As long as the number of jobs is reasonable, who cares?

Comment: @StefanHanke. Did [Copy Artifacts](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) plugin worked for you? We are going to create more than 500 Jobs in Jenkins. For this case it is really not possible to add 38MB files each and every time. That's why we are looking for another option to handle it.

Comment: I didn't even try - I used `robocopy` (a fast windows copy tool) to copy the product to different directories (nightly) in the one shared workspace to avoid sharing problems. Maybe you can reduce the number of jobs or assign the same workspace to job groups. Furthermore I cannot imagine how you would manage 500 jobs with the default UI...